# Adding additional CSS files to WordPress theme editor

Tags: css, wordpress, editor

I have created a WordPress themes with all the necessary templates (PHP files). However under "Styles" it's currently only showing the style.css file. I understand I can @import CSS files in style.css but I wanna be able to edit those additional CSS files from my theme directly in the WordPress theme editor, like I can with style.css.

Seems silly to have a whole "Styles" heading in the theme editor if you can't even add other CSS files?

So is it possible to make extra CSS files show up in the theme editor?

[image: WordPress theme editor files list]

Answer (score 0):

Just create another stylesheet in your theme folder and it will show up in the theme editor. You can then edit that stylesheet from there.

You can import that css in your style.css or can enqueue style if you want.

Comment: My additional CSS files are in /assets/css/ which is why i guess they don't show up. They have to be in root like style.css which isn't great for organization but I will have to live with it. Thanks.

Comment: yeah. css files under different folder wont be editable.